# AWS-s3 : How to copy files from s3 bucket to another s3 bucket based on filename

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

using the below code , Im able to list the files in s3 bucket. I would like to know how to copy/move the files from s3 one bucket (s3-dev) to another s3 bucket(s3-prod) based on file names. eg if a file with name "abc-21-04-2021.csv" is placed in s3 Bucket (s3-dev) , how to find the filename starting with "abc" and copy/move to another s3 bucket.

consider the files in s3-dev Bucket as 1)abc-21-04-2021.csv, 2)abc-19-04-2021.csv, 3)def-18-04-2021.csv , i need to move files starting with "abc" into another s3 bucket (s3-prod).

please suggest and share your inputs.

````
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('s3-dev')

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(my_bucket_object.key)```
````

Comment: my suggestions :- 
list the entire bucket, store the list of objets in a list, extract objects starting with abc using grep, store those  objects in a different list and just copy those object to another bucket from that new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your code written in python, you just need to handle the bucket object as string.

```
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('s3-dev')

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    file_name =  my_bucket_object.key.split('/')[-1] # avoid the folder contains the pattern
    if file_name.startswith('abc'):
        print(my_bucket_object.key)
```